# A necessary and sufficient condition of $v<<\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

The question is too long to write down in the title.Here is the explanation:

Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure on $R$, $\{x_k\}$ is a series of points on $R$,$\delta_k$ is the Dirac measure on $x_k$,Let $\mu =m+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\delta_k$;then let $v$ be the real Borel measure on $R$.

prove:

$v<<\mu$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ there exits a Borel measurable function $f\in L^1(R,m)$,$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|f(x_k)|<+\infty$, and for each Borel set $E\subset R$,we have $$v(E)=\int_{E}f(x)d\mu.$$

OK,it's easy to see that when the right part stands,for any $\mu(E)=0$,the $v(E)=\int_{E}f(x)d\mu=0$,which means the "$\Longleftarrow$" is easy to solve. However the inverse stucked me, I have no idea to do it,not a single direction,but I still found something maybe useful, that's the Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym theorem, and I was stucked here, don't know how to go further.

Comment: What does your radon nikodym theorem say?

Comment: @Timkinsella just the one you can find in the wiki.I don't know if it's really useful,I just find similar things between them.Or You can just ignore what i said :)